# How to encode SPECIAL CHARACTER with Base64 in Java

Tags: java, android, base64

I'm trying to build an app on Android which uses Base64 encoding.
Creating a String "\uDE00" creates an object with hashCode of 56832. Encoding and Decoding this string with Base64 creates an object with hashCode of 65533.

Is there any way to keep the original string using Base64? These values are used in HashMap, so the code can't work correctly.

Theese are the methods I use:

private static final String CHARSET = "UTF-16";

```
private static String encodeToBase64(@NonNull String string) {
    return Base64.encodeToString(string.getBytes(Charset.forName(CHARSET)), 0);
}

private static String decodeBase64(@NonNull String string) {
    return new String(Base64.decode(string, 0), Charset.forName(CHARSET));
}
```

Comment: String a = "\uDE00";
new String(a.getBytes("UTF-16"), "UTF-16").equals(a) => false ??